# How do I start WebSphere 6.x admin service without starting my apps?

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

How do I start WebSphere 6.x admin service without starting my apps?  Does anyone know how to do this (if its even possible)?

Since my app takes about 5+ minutes to start, I am hoping I can start the admin first , then login to the GUI and then manually start my app from the GUI.   Another reason I want to do this is because the .ear update/upgrade process goes much faster if the app is turned off first and then I update the code and then I restart the app.   If I try to update on the fly it seems to take much longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the default start up properties for the application to "Stopped".

The default is to start the applications as part of server start up.

Enterprise Applications --> Target Specific Application Status --> Disable Auto Start

I am assuming that you are a stand alone set up.  If you are on ND environment, administration is essentially performed using the deployment manager and your application servers need not run for the activities to be performed.